# How do I target the first item in a Twig for loop?

Tags: entries

I'm looping through some images and want to target just the first image. How do I do that?

```
{% for image in entry.images %}
<img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If the “loop” is an [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) object, then you can grab the first element using [`.first()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#outputting-elements):

```
{% set blogPost = craft.entries.section('blog').order('posdDate desc').first() %}
--
{% set image = entry.myAssetsField.first() %}
--
{% set firstTextBlock = entry.myMatrixField.type('text').first() %}
```

However if it’s just a normal array, then you will need to grab the `[0]` syntax instead, or Twig’s [`|first` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/first.html).

```
{% set updates = craft.feeds.getFeedItems('http://buildwithcraft.com/updates.rss') %}
{% set latestUpdate = updates[0] %}
--
{% set primaryLocale = craft.i18n.getSiteLocaleIds()|first %}
```

Note that the `[0]` and `|first` syntaxes are available to ElementCriteriaModel objects as well, and there’s no performance penalty for using those. `.first()` was the only one you could use originally, but that changed in Craft 1.3. I still prefer `.first()` when it can be used, just because it looks a little cleaner and jQuery-esque.

One warning about `[0]`: If the array/ElementCriteriaModel doesn’t have a first item, and if Dev Mode is enabled, Twig will give you an error.

Bad:

```
{% set firstItem = myArray[0] %}
{% if firstItem %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Good:

```
{% if myArray[0] is defined %}
    {% set firstItem = myArray[0] %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

With `|first` and `.first()` it’s the other way around, though:

Bad:

```
{% if myArray|first is defined %}
    {% set firstItem = myArray|first %}
    ...
{% endif %}

--

{% if entry.myAssetsField.first() is defined %}
    {% set firstItem = entry.myAssetsField.first() %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Good:

```
{% set firstItem = myArray|first %}
{% if firstItem %}
    ...
{% endif %}

--

{% set firstItem = entry.myAssetsField.first() %}
{% if firstItem %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 34):

Twig has [loop-variables](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) which can be accessed inside for-loops. `loop.first` will return true on the first iteration.

```
{% for image in entry.images %}
    <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">

    {% if loop.first %}
        Do stuff..
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
{% for image in entry.images %}
    {% if loop.first %}
         <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
    {% elseif loop.last %}
          <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
    {% else %}
          <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It can be done with loop.first & loop.last

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if you are asking how to grab just the first image, or manipulate just the first image in a loop. You can use `.first()` on asset fields to grab the first asset in the array only.

You can also do all kinds of cool things with loops in twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

To manipulate just the first image within the loop, you would use `loop.first`

Comment: I believe `entry.images[0]` would work as well.